# How to merge mutilple RDD in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I want to merge multiple RDD into one using a key. Instead of doing join multiple times, is there an effcient way to do so?

For example:

```
Rdd_1 = [(0, a), (1, b), (2, c), (3, d)]
Rdd_2 = [(0, aa), (1, bb), (2, cc), (3, dd)]
Rdd_3 = [(0, aaa), (1, bbb), (2, ccc), (3, ddd)]
```

I expected output should look like

```
Rdd = [(0, a, aa, aaa), (1, b, bb, bbb), (2, c, cc, ccc), (3, d, dd, ddd)]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for completeness here is the join method:

```
 Rdd_1.join(Rdd_2).join(Rdd_3).map(lambda (x,y): (x,)+y[0]+(y[1],))
```

In terms of efficiency if you explicitly partition each `rdd` on the key (using `partitionBy`) then all the tuples to be joined will sit in the same partition and this will make it more efficient.